# Timer callback with low precision in microsecond with thread and lock in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, callback, condition-variable, time-precision

I wrote a `timercallback` class that doesn't run fast enough:

```
class Manager
{
    ...
    void CallFunction(Function<Treturn>* m_function)
    {
        do
        {
            if (m_Status == TimerStatus::Paused)
            {
                unique_lock<mutex> lock(m_MutexLock);
                m_Notifier.wait(lock);
            }
            while (m_Status != TimerStatus::Stoped&&m_Status != TimerStatus::Paused)
            {
                unique_lock<mutex> lock(m_MutexLock);
                m_Notifier.wait_for(lock, m_Interval);

                (*m_function)();
            }

        } while (m_Status == TimerStatus::Paused);
    }
    ...
}
```

When I set the time of timercallback to call the function every 1ms it doesn't work. It takes more, for example 10 ms. I need help to improve the code to call the callback function (event function of this timer) in 1 ms intervals and run in one thread with lock. How can I do this?

Sample of use this class:

```
Manager tester;
TimerCallback<microseconds> m_timer(chrono::microseconds(10), Core::Utility::ptr_fun(&tester, &Manager::runner));
```

Comment: First, what do you mean you need this code below 1ms? Which part? And second, you need way more context than this. Take a read of [mcve]

Comment: Yes you're right @PasserBy.

Comment: for explain problem : when set time of timercallback to call function every 1ms don't call and take more for example 10 ms. I need help for improve code to call callback function (event function of this timer) in 1 ms

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the `wait_for()` function as a timer which is really not a good way to have a high precision timer. If you need the mutex functionality, though, that's pretty much all you'll get.

If you use the mutex to get signals, then maybe you could switch to using [`ppoll()`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ppoll&sektion=2&n=1). The function can also be used without any events, with just a timeout, then it works as a timer.

Another solution is to simply use the [`nanosleep()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) function. This is much simpler than the `ppoll()` call since all you need is a `timespec` structure:

```
struct timespec t = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = 1'000'000 };
nanosleep(&t);
```

**Side note:**

From my experience with VirtualBox, a VM clock precision is abysmal. In other words, you are very unlikely to get a reliable 1ms sleep between calls on such a system. I do not know whether that applies to Cloud based VMs (which probably use better solutions than VirtualBox, but probably are in a similar situation with timers).